# Not updating TextView value with thread,Why?

Tags: android, multithreading

```
TextView output;
int i;
    Random random=new Random();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        output=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        new Thread(new mythread()).start();
        }

        class mythread implements Runnable{

            @Override
            public void run() {
try {
                    while(true) {
                        i = random.nextInt(100);
                        output.setText(i + "");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
    }catch (Exception e){}
       }
     }
  }
```

it just showing one number in text view 
but requirement is ,it should generate random number and keep updating textview after 500ms
Thank You!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, I think it will solved your problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Random random;
        private Handler handler;
        private TextView textView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            displayRandomNumber();
        }

        /**
         * Display random number in text view
         */
        private void displayRandomNumber()
        {
            random = new Random();
            handler = new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int value = random.nextInt();
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                    handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: provide a solution without a line of explanation is not useful for the community, this is not a platform to solve other exercises but he help and learn, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, in your code, is that you can update UI only in the main thread and you are using a custom thread.

The second problem is that you are using Thread.sleep that is a very bad practise.

I suggest you to use Handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Handler", "Running Handler");
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                }
            }

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```

and here the kotlin version

```
    var handler = Handler()
    var runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d("Handler", "Running Handler");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
        }
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500)
```

Comment: Really appreciate but  I need a simplest form of program that will generate random number using thread 
is any possibility to update my code strictly  with thread.sleep() method
I am newbie in android development and just started month ago 
i am learning this step by step and just with simple programs like this 
Thank You

Comment: this is more simple and clean solution you can use, I suggest you read Handler documentation =)  trust me

Comment: can you provide complete code as a solution of my question with those handler concept  which u told me before? 
It will be more helpful to me 
on that basis i will learn the new things related to this!!